# click print all button and prints all the images print in one shot

Tags: php, html

I have created multiple images display from a folder as thumbnail. 
I want click print all button and prints all the images print in one shot.

it is possible do print all images at the same time .?

The technologies I am using:

PHP5.x/HTML5/CSS3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to print all the images in one batch. Here are two topics that may help you:

[Javascript window.print() function :](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)
triggers the printing of a page (I.E. same behavior as pressing CTRL-P with your standard browser).

[CSS Media queries :](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)
allows you to specify a different stylesheet for each media.(print, screen, handheld...) You could specify a stylesheet hiding everything but your images for the 'print' media.

I may also ask : what have you tried so far?